# Windows authentication not working when running visual studio in administrator with different credentials?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, iis

I'm running an asp.net application in visual studio 2015 using different credential to run in administrator mode. My application is using windows authentication to run but it seems that the windows authentication not working.

I am getting username as machinename\name instead of domain\username.

Comment: Are you using IIS or IIS Express?

Comment: @MikeMat I am using IIS to run the application